# UIRefreshControl not showing with QuickDialog and iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uirefreshcontrol

I'm using UIRefreshControl to allow pull to down refresh on a QuickDialog controller.

I use the following code:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshVehicles:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[vc.quickDialogTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

Everything is working fine on iOS6 and XCode 4 but when I've tried to build the app using XCode 5 for iOS7 the refresh control is not shown.

Any idea why can happen?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of QuickDialog?

Comment: Yes, I updated it before posting the question.